# pyspark filter an array of structs based on one value in the struct

Tags: arrays, pyspark, struct

I have a a df with an array of structs:

When I call df.dtypes for this column I would get:

('forminfo', 'array<struct<id: string, code: string>>')

I want to create a new column called 'forminfo_approved' which takes my array and filters within that array to keep only the structs with code == "APPROVED". So if I did a df.dtypes on this new field, the type would be the same, (another array of structs) but I would only have the APPROVED structs from the array.

I've played around with udf's and expr's for a long time now and I can't quite seem to get this one to perform the behavior above. Thanks so much if you can help!

Christie

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it:

```py
df.withColumn("forminfo_approved", expr("filter(form_info, s-> s.code == 'APPROVED')"))
```